# What is the solution to this equation: $e^x+2x=0$

Tags: problem-solving

I cant find any program that actually solves this type of equations and I cant find anything helpful about this type. What is the name of these equations and how do I solve this one? Thanks.

Comment: It's a transcendent equation and this equation has no solutions in elementary functions.

Comment: Plot the two curves: $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = -2x$. Use desmos for it

Comment: No book will ask that, they might have asked you the number of solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by no solutions in elementary functions?  The graph shows that is crosses the x-axis at the point -0.35...

Comment: This cannot be solved algebraically.  There is a special function of these sorts of problems, the Lambert W function.  $x = -W(\frac 12)$

Comment: @Antonis See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Comment: Use the bisection method.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRozenberg for the info.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

$$e^x=-2x$$
$$1=-2xe^{-x}$$
$$-xe^{-x}=\frac12$$
$$-x=W_k\left(\frac12\right)$$
$$\therefore x=-W_k\left(\frac12\right)$$
Where $W_k(z)$ is the $k$th branch of the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The only real solution is
$$x=-W_0\left(\frac12\right)=-0.35173371124919582602490930092995106517146421551711180404\dots$$
but there are infinitely many complex solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's method is a good numerical method for solving this transcendental equation.

Graphing shows that $x_0\approx-\frac{1}{3}$ is a good initial approximation.

Newton's method provides a sequence of better approximations provided the initial guess is sufficiently close:

\begin{eqnarray}
x_{n+1}&=&x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f^\prime(x_n)}\\
&=&x_n-\frac{e^{x_n}+2x_n}{e^{x_n}+2}
\end{eqnarray}

Using $x_0=-\dfrac{1}{3}$ we get the sequence

\begin{eqnarray}
x_1&=&-0.3516893316\\
x_2&=&-0.3517337110\\
x_3&=&-0.3517337112\\
x_4&=&-0.3517337112
\end{eqnarray}

So it converges rather quickly using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Such an equation does not have an easy formula or a "closed form" like quadratic formula for example. If you only care about the answer, you can try to plot it as in [Plot using Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e7vzzuskhf) .It turns out that it has a real root at approximately: $x=-0.352$.

Alternatively you could try a "numerical method" such as Newtons's iterative method. Such methods start at a guess and keep on improving the assumption by applying a formula. See for example:
[Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Answer (score 0):

This is a transcendental equation. As said by others, it has no closed-form expression using the standard functions.

The derivative of the function is

$$(f(x))'=(e^x+2x)'=e^x+2.$$ As it is positive, the function is increasing and has at most one root.

Now we can search for a change of sign, by trial an error.

We first observe $$f(0)=1$$ and the next value to try must be negative. Then

$$f(-1)=e^{-1}-2<0$$ and we know that the root is in $(-1,0)$.

---

From this, we draw a first approximation, by the secant method, giving

$$x\approx\frac{e}{1-3e}=-0.379921\cdots$$

Now by one iteration of Newton,

$$x\approx -0.379921-\frac{e^{-0.379921}+2(-0.379921)}{e^{-0.379921}+2}\approx-0.351631$$

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To have an estimate, expand as a Taylor series
$$e^x+2x=1+3 x+\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Solve the quadratic to get
$$x_0=\sqrt{7}-3\approx -0.354249$$ More "funny" would be the $[1,n]$ Padé approximant. Depending on $n$, you would get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_0^{(n)} =  & x_0^{(n)} \approx \\
 0 &  -\frac{1}{3} &   -0.33333333   \\
 1 &  -\frac{6}{17} &  -0.35294118   \\
 2 &  -\frac{51}{145} &    -0.35172414 \\
 3 &  -\frac{580}{1649} &    -0.35172832 \\
 4 &  -\frac{8245}{23441} &    -0.35173414 \\
 5 &  -\frac{140646}{399865} &    -0.35173371 \\
 6 &  -\frac{2799055}{7957881} &    -0.35173371
\end{array}
\right)$$